# Binary search tree insertion (C)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Thanks, now for some reason it's not working as intended. When I run the program it just gives an error "bst.exe has stopped working" and it happens in this function.

```
static NODE *insert_i(NODE *r, int x)
{
    NODE *leaf;

    while(r)
    {
        if(r->val == x)
            return r;

        if(x < r->val && r->left != NULL)
            r = r->left;

        else if(x > r->val && r->right != NULL)
            r = r->right;
    }

    leaf = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    leaf->left = NULL;
    leaf->right = NULL;
    leaf->val = x;
    count++;

    if(x < r->val)
        r->left = leaf;

    else
        r->right = leaf;

    return r;
}


void bst_insert(BST_PTR t, int x)
{
    t->root = insert_i(t->root, x);
}
```

Comment: if (r == NULL) // new tree ... this should be before the while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
while(r)
{
    if(r == NULL)
```

The `if` condition will *never* be true, as if `r` is `NULL` then the loop will end, without returning anything from the function.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if you `while` loop is not entered or exited without returning? It will not return anything and behaviour will be undefined.

So, return NULL to indicate that not found or move `if(r==NULL)` out of the loop. It will not be executed inside the loop.